# Why does this login.php not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck trying to create login code with PHP and MySQL. When I click the login button, even if the username and password are correct it does not go to the next page: it simply refreshes the login.php page. I'm not sure what the problem is in my code.

This same code works on a local server, but on the internet it doesn't.

```
       <?php
session_start();
include './db_connect.php';

$error = " " ;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password =md5($_POST['password']);
    if((!isset($username)) || ($username=="") || (!$username == " ") || (!isset($password)) || ($password=="") || (!$password == " ")){
    $error = "Please enter the details";
    }
    else{
         $username = $_POST['username'];
         $password =md5($_POST['password']);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");

                $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                 $username_db = $row['admin_name'];
                 $password_db = $row['password'];



                if(($username == $username_db) && ($password ==$password_db) )
                                    {  
                                    header ("Location:admin_hotel_details.php");
                                       $_SESSION['username']=$username_db;

                    }

                    else{

                        $error = "Username and password do not    match";

                        }

        }   
  }

   ?>
```

This is admin.php (my form code)

```
<form name="" action="admin.php" method="post">
      <style type="text/css">
      label{width:130px;}
      </style>
      <table cellpadding="4" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><span style="color:#F00;">
      <?php
      if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
      $msg = $_GET['msg'];
      $error = "Successfully logged out";
      }
      if(isset($error)){echo $error;} 
      ?>
      </span></td>
      </tr>



      <tr>
      <td style="width:150px;"><label for="username">Username: <span style="color:#F00;">*</span>:</label></td>
      <td style="width:100px;">
      <input type="username" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" style="width:205px" />
      </td>
      </tr>


      <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;"><label for="password">Password:<span style="color:#F00;">*</span>:</label></td>
      <td style="width:100px;"><input type="password" name="password" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" id="password" style="width:205px;" /></td>
      </tr> 



      <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="width:100px;">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
      </td>
      </tr>  

      </table>
      </form>
```

I also tried a different login.php

```
         <?php 

    include("./db_connect.php");
    session_start();
    $error = " " ;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Username and password sent from form in HTML
        $myusername = $_POST['username'];
        $mypassword = md5($_POST['password']);

        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = '".$myusername."' and password ='".$mypassword."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($sql));
        $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $count  = mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if ($count == 1) {

            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

            header("location:admin_hotel_details.php");
        } else {
            $error = "Your username or password is invalid";
        }
    }
   ?>
```

This gives me the same problem (at header place).

Comment: Can you please post your form code.

Comment: im wondering if the ECHO infront of your variable assignments is sending content out to the browser which would make the header function fail.  You have to set headers before content

Comment: check if mysql_query generates any mysql error like $query = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: `md5 + mysql_* = disaster`

Comment: And this `if((!isset($username)) || ($username=="") || (!$username == " ") || (!isset($password)) || ($password=="") || (!$password == " "))` it's contradicting itself.

Comment: @marc no problems in selecting query its echo the fetched value, no problem in mysql...but in header location not taking that page

Comment: @Aidan ITS MY FORM CODE CHECK IT

Comment: What is the page name of both files? Is the page you have your form on called admin.php? If so that would be the issue, it is pointing at itself and not at the separate php file you have.

Comment: @Aidan  php login code and form code page ll be the same...when click login it redirecting to same page then read the login code if username password matches its should redirect to admin_hotel_details.php..but even if matching also not redirecting   to admin_hotel_details.php page..its my problem    .and as you told that even i created separate file for html and php in that case also i am facing same problem can u suggest me some idea

Comment: @Aidan can you find out the problem

Comment: For starters remove, (!$username == " ") and (!$password == " ") from the if statement, they will be causing anything that is not a single space to throw an error. Also you do not need $username = $_POST['username']; $password =md5($_POST['password']); in your else statement as they are already defined before the if statement.

Comment: @Aidan  see this code as u told i modify it to this code page name login.php

Comment: @Marc can u able to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to clean up your code a little based on the comments I posted. See if this works for you.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include './db_connect.php';

    $error = " " ;
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password =md5($_POST['password']);
        if($username=="" || $password==""){
            $error = "Please enter the details";
        }else{
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_name = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'");

            if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                header("Location:admin_hotel_details.php");
            }else{
                $error = "Username and password do not match";
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Aiden you know one thing what are all the code we discussed..that works well in localhost,,but when we hosted in real time server its not working properly,,,its the major issue

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What is happening when you run the page? Do you get a white screen when you use the internet server? It may not have PHP installed in that instance.

Comment: @Aiden its simply refreshing ,,u just check it luxurykarnataka.com/admin.php  uname:ADMIN pswd:ADMIN

Comment: Can you add this some where on the page so we can see if it is working ? <?php echo "<font color='red'>".$error."</font>"; ?>

Comment: @Aiden Nothing i get..u just simply check that link .then u got know about that

Comment: Can you put that above code in the right after the <body> tag to make sure it displays.

Comment: Add this to the top of your PHP code, just so we can see if it is displaying at all $error = "THIS IS A TEST";

Comment: Also, can you change your php code, to the code in my example.

Comment: @Aiden..no more suggestion?

Comment: in my code above, can you add the following after the last } and before the ?>.     else{$error="CODE NOT GETTING IN IF";}

Comment: @Aiden ya getting ,,that else condition before submitting login button

Comment: @Aiden but after submitting same thing i getting,,,,what do bro.

Comment: It means that the script is not getting past the if statement, if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ . So that gives us some where to work from now

Comment: what is in this file? include './db_connect.php';

Comment: mysql connect file$host="localhost";
$user="luxuryka_karnataka123";
$password="karna123";
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
if(!$con)
{
die("connection to database failed".mysql_error());
}

$dataselect = mysql_select_db("luxuryka_karnataka",$con);
if(!$dataselect)
{
die("Database name list not selected".mysql_error());
}

Comment: Can you put $error="INSIDE IF"; straight after the first if statement

Comment: i did it,,it works well that db_connect.php .really yar i tried many more times but still i didnt get the output

Comment: you not getting any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use script in error.

```
        header("location: admin_hotel_details.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        //Login failed
            echo "<script>alert('INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD!');
                window.location='index.php';
                </script>";
```